# Bibliography and elsarticle

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to complile an elsarticle tex document. Although I dont get errors, the bibliographt doesn's seem to work. All I get is "elsarticle-harv" written.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{BHL}
\begin{thebibliography}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}   
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the bib file:

```
@Article{BHL,
author={Bjørnland, Hilde C. and Leitemo, Kai},
title={Identifying the interdependence between US monetary policy and the stock      market},
journal={Journal of Monetary Economics},
year=2009,
volume={56},
number={2},
pages={275-282},
month={March},
keywords={ VAR Monetary policy Asset prices Identification},
abstract={We estimate the interdependence between US monetary policy and the S\&P 500 using structural vector autoregressive (VAR) methodology. A solution is proposed to the simultaneity problem of identifying monetary and stock price shocks by using a combination of short-run and long-run restrictions that maintains the qualitative properties of a monetary policy shock found in the established literature [Christiano, L.J., Eichenbaum, M., Evans, C.L., 1999. Monetary policy shocks: what have we learned and to what end? In: Taylor, J.B., Woodford, M. (Eds.), Handbook of Macroeconomics, vol. 1A. Elsevier, New York, pp. 65-148]. We find great interdependence between the interest rate setting and real stock prices. Real stock prices immediately fall by seven to nine percent due to a monetary policy shock that raises the federal funds rate by 100 basis points. A stock price shock increasing real stock prices by one percent leads to an increase in the interest rate of close to 4 basis points.},
url={http://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/moneco/v56y2009i2p275-282.html}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `\usepackage` should be in the preamble. Eliminate the `thebibliography` environment. Just use `\bibliographstyle{}` and `\bibliography{}`.

Comment: Now I get loads of error...one of them: argument of \@citex has an extra }. ...irÃ¡ \cite{BHL}/Use of \@lbibitem doesn't match its definition. \bibitem[{Bjørnland and Leitemo(2009)}]{BHL}/Undefined control sequence. \bibitem[{Bjørnland and Leitemo(2009)}]{BHL}... Any help? EDIT: As I compile, errors seem to change back and forth...

Comment: Without a complete, compilable example, it isn't possible to say what is causing the errors. There is no `\citex` in your example, for instance, and I do not have `bib.bib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must delete (or comment out) the statements `\begin{bibliography}` and `\end{bibliography}`. Do add the instruction `\section*{References}` (or `\section*{Bibliography}` immediately before the `\bibliography{bib}` instruction.

Do also remember that all `\usepackage` statements must occur in the preamble.

Since some of your bib entries have long URL strings, I suggest you also load the `url` package. And, don't forget to encase words in the `title` field that shouldn't get lowercased in curly braces. (For the entry at hand, the word "US" qualifies for this treatment -- it definitely shouldn't get typeset as "us"...)

The results from the full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@Article{BHL,
author={Bjørnland, Hilde C. and Leitemo, Kai},
title={Identifying the interdependence between {US} monetary policy and the stock market},
journal={Journal of Monetary Economics},
year=2009,
volume={56},
number={2},
pages={275-282},
keywords={ VAR Monetary policy Asset prices Identification},
url={http://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/moneco/v56y2009i2p275-282.html}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url} %% new
\begin{document}
\cite{BHL}
%%%\begin{thebibliography}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  
\section*{References} %% new
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{bib}
%%%\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tried these but sill no help. I still get loads of errors... Maybe some package could be causing some conflict? Also, the bibliography is not coming out quite right; no special characters or numbering...

Comment: Thanks it does work. But strangely, it worked when I copied yours to a new file. Trying to change my old file did not do the trick. What is going on?

Comment: @MJS - With the old file, did you rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes?

Comment: Yes I did... although I did not delete the old files.

Comment: How can I get the bibliography to be numbered?

Comment: @MJS - Use `\section` instead of `\section*`?

Comment: I meant the entries, the study I am actually referencing. As in [1] Bjorn... etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19266/discussion-between-mjs-and-mico).

Comment: If you want numeric-style instead of authoryear-style citation callouts, you should (a) delete the option `authoryear` from the `\documentclass` instruction and (b) load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`.

Comment: @Mico: so the default setup does not print the "References" heading?

Comment: @enzotib - If by "default setup" you mean the one of the `elsarticle` document class, you are correct.

Comment: Keep in mind that `elsarticle` class already loads `natbib`, so you don't need `\usepackage{natbib}` in your preamble

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Just a simple trick solved it for me. `Elsarticle` uses `natbib`, so, I deleted the `cite` package in my file. Then, everything runs fine. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!